# Redirect after post-request and autocomplete formData

Tags: javascript, post, request, autocomplete, form-data

Need to make a post request with sending formData

[How it works can be viewed and yanked on this page

https://www.flybaghdad.net/en

Fill in the fields in the form, click "Search Flights" and there is a redirection to the page

[https://booking.flybaghdad.net/ibe/IF/home?language=en#searchForm|](https://stackoverflow.com)](https://booking.flybaghdad.net/ibe/IF/home?language=en#searchForm%7C%5D(https://stackoverflow.com))

Which contains another form but already autofilled fields from the previous form
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOt3w.png)

the server answers the code 200, but I need to redirect to the site with the fields filled in the query

```
await fetch("https://booking.flybaghdad.net/ibe/IF/home?language=en", {
    method: "POST",
    body: datas,
    headers: {
      "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
 "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      
       
    },
  })
```

I tried to transfer parameters to the URL, but it does not work

Comment: Hi coremraz and welcome to SO. It's unclear what you're asking, is the problem that you're unable to pass parameters to another page or are you asking how to redirect? Could you show us your attempt you're referring to in your last paragraph?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier url + payload in URI encode

Comment: Please show how you've tried to solve it, what values you're trying to send, the page you're trying to redirect, anything that helps us figure what you're trying to make.